# How to implement argmax in ruby?

Tags: ruby, json

Given a json array:

```
[{ "x":"5", "y":"20" },{ "x":"6", "y":"10" },{ "x":"50", "y":"5" }]
```

I'd like to find `argmax(x)`, such that I can do `puts argmax(arr, :arg => "x").y` and get `5`. How can I elegantly implement this in Ruby?

**Edit**: Clarified a bit. The idea is that you can specify the field of an element in a list that you want to maximize and the method will return the maximizing element.

Comment: what do you have so far? It's easier to propose beautification on specific pieces of code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `Enumerable#max_by`. To get `y` like you're saying, it would be:

```
arr.max_by {|hash| hash['x']}['y']
```

(Well, actually, you'll want the numbers to be numbers instead of strings, since '50' sorts lower than '6'. But I think you get the idea. You can `to_i` or do whatever processing you need in the block to get the "real" value to sort by.)